# bash: sorting on same values gives different orders

Tags: bash, sorting

I have the following two files:

file1:

```
4   rs10000009  0   71048953    G   A
4   rs10000010  0   21618674    C   T
4   rs10000011  0   138223055   T   C
2   rs1000001   0   50711642    T   G
4   rs10000005  0   85161558    G   A
12  rs1000000   0   126890980   A   G
4   rs10000003  0   57561647    A   G
4   rs10000006  0   108826383   C   T
4   rs10000007  0   114553253   C   A
4   rs10000008  0   172776204   T   C
```

file2:

```
4    rs10000007    C    A     0.006562      762
4    rs10000008    T    C      0.01575      762
4    rs10000009    G    A            0      762
12     rs1000000    A    G       0.2388      762
4    rs10000010    C    T       0.4921      762
4    rs10000003    A    G       0.2992      762
4    rs10000005    G    A       0.4409      762
4    rs10000012    G    C       0.1417      762
4    rs10000006    C    T      0.02625      762
4    rs10000011    T    C      0.03675      762
```

I use sort to sort these files based on column 2, which contains the same values for both files.

```
sort -f -k 2 file1 > file1.sorted
sort -f -k 2 file2 > file2.sorted
```

However, I get two *differently* sorted files:

file1.sorted:

```
12  rs1000000   0   126890980   A   G
4   rs10000003  0   57561647    A   G
4   rs10000005  0   85161558    G   A
4   rs10000006  0   108826383   C   T
4   rs10000007  0   114553253   C   A
4   rs10000008  0   172776204   T   C
4   rs10000009  0   71048953    G   A
4   rs10000010  0   21618674    C   T
2   rs1000001   0   50711642    T   G
4   rs10000011  0   138223055   T   C
```

file2.sorted:

```
4    rs10000003    A    G       0.2992      762
4    rs10000005    G    A       0.4409      762
4    rs10000006    C    T      0.02625      762
4    rs10000007    C    A     0.006562      762
4    rs10000008    T    C      0.01575      762
4    rs10000009    G    A            0      762
12     rs1000000    A    G       0.2388      762
4    rs10000010    C    T       0.4921      762
4    rs10000011    T    C      0.03675      762
4    rs10000012    G    C       0.1417      762
```

What am I missing here? How do I get these two files to be sorted in the same way? It does not matter much to me in which way, as long as I can then use join to join the two files. Many thanks!

Comment: you probably need to use `-k 2,2`

Comment: see this excellent answer for further details: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104525/sort-based-on-the-third-column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-k 2,2` to sort based on 2nd column alone. `-k 2` means sort starting from 2nd column

```
$ sort -f -k 2,2 file2
12     rs1000000    A    G       0.2388      762
4    rs10000003    A    G       0.2992      762
4    rs10000005    G    A       0.4409      762
4    rs10000006    C    T      0.02625      762
4    rs10000007    C    A     0.006562      762
4    rs10000008    T    C      0.01575      762
4    rs10000009    G    A            0      762
4    rs10000010    C    T       0.4921      762
4    rs10000011    T    C      0.03675      762
4    rs10000012    G    C       0.1417      762
```

Use `-b` option to **ignore leading blanks**, for ex: `sort -bf -k 2,2 file2`

Further reading: [Sort based on the third column](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104525/sort-based-on-the-third-column)

Comment: `sort -f -k 2,2 file1` gives `12  rs1000000   0   126890980   A   G` as last row, I have `sort (GNU coreutils) 8.25`

Comment: @anubhava, same version for me `sort (GNU coreutils) 8.25`... output is identical whether I use `-f` or `-bf`.. and `12 rs1000000 0 126890980 A G` is first row for file2...

Comment: @anubhava, I think the difference could be due to `locale` settings.. trying to see if I can replicate your output based on http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104525/sort-based-on-the-third-column

Comment: May be it behaves differently on OSX. I even tried `LC_ALL=C gsort -f -k 2,2 file1`

Comment: I think it is safer to use `-b` option which would work in all cases... will update answer, thanks